# Maximal Ideals of $\mathbb{R}[x]/(x^2 - 3x + 2)$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

I have a question on a solution I was reading from the following link: https://brianbi.ca/artin/11.8

The question is 11.8.2 part (c) and reads:

Determine the maximal ideals of each of the following rings:

part (c): $\mathbb{R}[x]/(x^2 - 3x + 2)$.

The solution author writes:

Let R = $\mathbb{R}[x]/(x^2 - 3x + 2)$ ... (let $\alpha$ be the residue of x)

... "Now R/($\alpha$ - 1) $\cong$ $\mathbb{R}[x]/(x -1, x^2 - 3x + 2 )$ = $\mathbb{R}[x]/(x-1)$ $\cong$ $\mathbb{R}$.

Why is the above true? I'm not sure why the first statement holds in particular, namely R/($\alpha$ - 1) $\cong$ $\mathbb{R}[x]/(x -1, x^2 - 3x + 2 $)

Thanks!

Comment: You haven't told us what $\alpha$ denotes.

Comment: it is the residue of x

Comment: This follows from the so-called third isomorphism theorem for rings, which says that if $I, J$ are ideals of a commutative ring $R$ such that $I \subseteq J$, then $(R/I)/(J/I) \cong R/J$, where $J/I$ denotes the image of the ideal $J$ under the canonical projection $R \to R/I$. As a special case, let $I, I'$ be any two ideals of a ring $A$, and let $J = I+I'$. Then $R/J \cong (R/I)/(J/I) \cong (R/I)/(I'/I)$, since the projection of $J$ to $R/I$ coincides with the projection of $I'$ to $R/I$. In our case, we have $R = \mathbb{R}[X], I = (X-1), I' = (X^{2}-3X+2)$.

Comment: Incidentally, while Brian's solution is fine, I think the better approach to this problem is to use the Chinese remainder theorem. As he observes $X^{2}-3X+2$ factors as $(X-1)(X-2)$. The ideals $(X-1)$ and $(X-2)$ of $\mathbb{R}[X]$ are comaximal, so $\mathbb{R}[X]/(X^{2}-3X+2) \cong \mathbb{R}[X]/(X-1) \times \mathbb{R}[X]/(X-2) \cong \mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R}$. It is very easy to identify the maximal ideals of the latter, which are $\mathbb{R} \times \{0\}$ and $\{0\} \times \mathbb{R}$. Pulling these ideals back under the CRT isomorphism recovers Brian's description.

Comment: ah ok so I like the Chinese remainder method much better, thanks. The CRT isomorphism just send an x -> (x mod I, x mod J)? @AlexWertheim

Comment: if you could be more explicit on the pulling back the ideals via the isomorphism, that would be greatly appreciated! @AlexWertheim

Comment: Yes, that's correct - the CRT isomorphism is indeed reduction via each ideal in each component. Put $J = (X^{2}-3X+2)$. The maximal ideal $\mathbb{R} \times \{0\}$ corresponds with the maximal ideal $\mathbb{R}[X]/(X-1) \times \{0\}$ of $\mathbb{R}[X]/(X-1) \times \mathbb{R}[X]/(X-2)$. The preimage of this ideal under the CRT is precisely the ideal of classes $f(X) + J$ such that the reduction of $f(X)$ mod $X-2$ is zero, i.e. those $f(X)$ which are divisible by $X-2$. Hence, the preimage is principal, generated by the class $(X-2) + J$. (Proceed identically with $\{0\} \times \mathbb{R}$.)

Answer (score 1):

We may see this as two morfisms. The first is $\phi : \mathbb{R}[x]\to R$ that sends $p(x) \mapsto p(x)+(x^2-3x+2)$. The second is $\varphi: R \to R/(\alpha + 1)$ that sends $p(x)+(x^2-3x+2) \mapsto (p(x)+(x^2-3x+2)) + (\alpha + 1)$ where $\alpha = x+(x^2-3x+2)$.

The composition $\varphi \circ \phi$ is a morfism that sends $\mathbb{R}[x]$ to $R/(\alpha + 1)$, let's take a look on its kernel:

$$(\varphi \circ \phi)^{-1}(0) = \phi^{-1}( \varphi^{-1}( \alpha + 1 ) ) = \varphi^{-1}( \alpha + 1 + (x^2-3x+2) ) = (x+1, x^2-3x+2)$$

Now, bringing the compositions back by the isomorphism theorem we got that:
$$ \frac{R}{(\alpha + 1)} \approx \frac{\mathbb{R}[x]}{ker(\varphi\circ\phi)} = \frac{\mathbb{R}[x]}{ (x+1, x^2-3x+2) } $$